# Возникло пустое пространство на сайте

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть `tab-content` из Bootstrap, в нём четыре `iframe`. Как видно [здесь](http://castit.tk/stream.html) между фреймом и счётчиком большое пустое пространство. Как от него избавиться?

Comment: у вас там nav nav-tabs padding-left:10%; это уберите

Comment: Вот [скриншот](https://i.gyazo.com/87c09eb19c7199b62eb0923017789d1d.png) . Есть просвет между панелью вкладок и фреймом. Там `<br>` стоит. Под фреймом стоят два счётчика, но просвет до них - пара миллиметров. Какое пустое пространство вы имеете в виду?

Answer (score 1):

html, body, .container {height: 100%;}